# Registering a decorated type in a Prism app DI container

Tags: dependency-injection, prism, decorator, ioc-container

I'm working on a WPF app using Prism with a DryIoc container.  The Prism part is the only thing that should matter.

Let's say I have an interface and two classes, where one is decorating the other and they depend on another type ID that needs to be resolved by the container:

```
public interface IA {
    void Method();
}

public class A : IA {
    public A(ID d) { ... }
    public void Method() { ... }
}

public class B : IA {
    public B(ID d, IA a) { ... }
    public void Method() { ... }
}
```

How do I register this with IContainerRegistry so when I ask for an IA I get a B that's initialized with an A?

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.Register<ID, D>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IA, A>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IA, B>(); // ?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I register this with IContainerRegistry so when I ask for an IA I get a B that's initialized with an A?

```
containerRegistry.Register<ID, D>();
containerRegistry.Register<IA>( c => new B( c.Resolve<ID>(), c.Resolve<A>() ) );
```

Yes, this is ugly and fragile. Therefore, I'd revisit the architecture and use generics to define the decorated type:

```
public class B<DecoratedType> : IA where DecoratedType : IA
{
    public B( ID d, DecoratedType a )
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

and

```
containerRegistry.Register<IA,B<A>>();
```

Disclaimer: I'm from an unity-background, and unity resolves concrete types without registration. If DryIOC doesn't do this, you have to add

```
containerRegistry.Register<A>();
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I'm just learning about Prism and DI and all this stuff, so I'm probably doing this all wrong.  I've already decided on doing it a different way, but it's good to know how to register decorators if I ever need to.

Answer (score 3):

I have a [working example here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/LearnWpfPrism/tree/main/src/apps/201200-SimpleDecorator) based on the [DryIoc docs here](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/Decorators.md#general-use-case).

```cs
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewA>();

    var container = PrismIocExtensions.GetContainer(containerRegistry);

    container.Register<IWelcomeService, WelcomeService>();
    container.Register<ILogger, InMemoryLogger>();
    container.Register<IWelcomeService, LoggerWelcomeService>(setup: Setup.Decorator);
}
```

Comment: +1 for `GetContainer` - noone needs an abstraction here, works as fine as abstracting away sql server and then replacing it with mysql and expecting it to work